# How To Make my Table of Rows Responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

Does anybody know how to make my table of rows and columns mobile responsive. I insert my data from the database, but they are not mobile responsive. The element1 and content1 id are for the background of the elements. Can you please tell me how to make my table of rows and columns mobile responsive?

Here is my html and php:

```
    <section>

    <table>

            <tr>
            <?php 
                $counter = 0;
                while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)){
                    if($counter % 4 == 0){
                        echo '</tr><tr>';
                    }
                    ++$counter;
                    ?>
                    <td>
                    <div id="element1"></div>
                    <div id="content1">
                        <img src="<?= $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?=         $product['title']; ?>">
                        <h4><?= $product['title']; ?></h4>
                        <hr>
                        <p class="description"><?= $product['description']; ?></p>

            <!--------BUTTON READ MORE-------->

            <div id="hovers">
                <a href="<?php echo $product['href']?>" class="button" target="_blank">
                    <span class="contentbut"> Read More</span>
                </a>
            </div>
                    </td>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </table>    
    </section>
```

Here is my css:

```
#element1{
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
    width:320px;
    height:380px;
    text-align:left;

    background: url('../interviewsbackground.png') no-repeat center;
    border:#F90 2px solid;

}

#content1{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    top: -380px;
    width:290px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:left;
    margin:34px;
    margin-bottom:-240px;
}


    /*-------------------------3D BUTTONS-----------------*/
    .button{
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    height:45px;
    position:relative;
    border:2px solid #04a;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    border-radius:5px;
     }

    .button .contentbut{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:6px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    line-height:50px;
    background-color:#09f;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 0 #06c;
    border-radius:5px;
    transition:all 0.ls linear;
     }
```

Comment: Define mobile responsive? What should change for the layout?

Comment: I need the rows to fit in a mobile phone view.

Comment: Try building an example that doesn't involve PHP. Tables are generally responsive by nature - (to some extent) - so, you probably mean the images... - you don't need to answer in the comments - they are meant to help you flush out your question - and 'fit in mobile view' isn't clear enough to be helpful.

Comment: Yes, but i need to insert my data from the database using php?

Comment: Well, a good start is to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to your index-file and then tweak your table so it looks "nice" on each device.

Comment: @Kaloyan The point of a question on StackOverflow is to define a problem clearly - and then to - as a community - find the best solution for that problem. The problem can't be 'my code is not working' - so I suggest a version of the problem that can be more easily reasoned about. It will help you see the edge cases. : )

Comment: Here is an example of how I might ask a question like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/dc3mh3wo/  - but the question still remains... what do you want to happen? 'Mobile Responsive' is what marketing people say. It doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have two simple options. You can either use percentage widths/heights in your css (for example doing so for all widths), or you can look at media targeting in your css which is more complicated but can give better designed results.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

You may also want to look at break points, although this is another step more complex. Percentages will probably suffice.

https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/

Comment: I highly recommend ignoring that link for 'standard-devices' - as there aren't really any. You're better off creating break-points based on when things get ugle.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the answer would be to ditch the table and use a list + media queries + flexbox. What you are displaying isn't tabular data. It'll clean up your need to spit out rows of 4 only and allow you to work with more screen sizes.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/0egLgmge/

This doesn't use your exact content - but I'm repurposing it from another answer - and I think it will make its point. : )

markup

```
<ul class='thing-list'>

  <li class='thing'>
    <a class='link' href='#'>
      <figure>
        <img src='https://placehold.it/800x1000' alt='thing poster'>
      </figure>
      <h1 class='title'>Title</h1>
      <div class='rating'>
        xxx
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  ...
```

styles

```
/* https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ */
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a { /* removes link defaults */
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: inherit;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

figure img { /* make img's in figures responsive to their parent */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.thing-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direct: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.thing-list .thing {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .thing-list .thing {
    flex-basis: 48%; /* these are very rough... */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .thing-list .thing {
    flex-basis: 30%;
  }
}

.thing-list .thing .link {
  display: block; /* this has children that are block - so it HAS to be block */
}

.thing-list .thing figure {
  /* */
}

.thing-list .thing .title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: lightgreen;
  color: white;
}

.thing-list .thing .rating {
  padding: 10px; /* you can use flexbox for these stars too */
}
```